# Restore DB2 backup to another DB2 database with different name

Tags: database, db2, database-restore, db2-luw

I have a DB2 10 database backup file that I would like to restore to another environment.  The problem is that the database has been setup with a different name and the restore complains because the database names are different.

Is there a way to restore the database backup file to the other environment?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to provide the actual `RESTORE` command that you used and the entire error message. By the way, DB2 v10 is only available on z/OS. Is this the platform we're talking about?

Comment: The restore command was `db2 restore database mydb from /tmp taken at 20151007243030` and it is on a Linux OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

In the end we dropped the existing database, restored the database from the backup file and then renamed the restored database to match the previous database name

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command I used to restore:

```
db2 "RESTORE DATABASE <restore database name> FROM <current restore directory> TAKEN AT <timestamp of full backup> TO <Local database directory> INTO <new database name>"
```

Example:

Database name of original backup is:

> SYSTEM

My backup directory is:

> /db2inst1/archive/backup/SYSTEM/level0/

Timestamp of original backup is:

> 20180503141925

Local database directory is: I would redirect this directory to your database standard list

New database name is:

> SYSTEM2

Example output command is:

```
db2 "RESTORE DATABASE system FROM /db2inst1/archive/backup/SYSTEM/level0/ TAKEN AT
20180503141925 TO /db2inst1/ INTO system2"
```

Once complete roll-forward database:

```
db2 "ROLLFORWARD DB SYSTEM2 TO END OF LOGS AND COMPLETE"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "redirected" restore option by generating a file

```
db2 restore database mydb redirect generate script restore.sql
```

Once the script is generated, you can change the names, file locations, etc.

And finally, execute the script

```
db2 -tvf restore.sql
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way of using the redirect option to redirect it to the database with the different name through the restore command?  I've seen this when I've been investigating the issue but not sure if I'm just misunderstood the purpose of this code.  I've not been able to get it to work though. `db2 restore database mydb from /tmp taken at 20151007243030 to new_ip_location into diff_name_db redirect without prompting`

Comment: "restore mydb redirect generated by restore.sql" doesn't look like valid command syntax.

Comment: @user3165854 Please read the syntax diagram for `restore database` command, options belong in a specific order.  Or, as @angoca suggests, use `generate script`.